# Phonegap build installing app onto emulator failing

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to run a clean build phonegap project but got an error.

```
...
[phonegap] installing app onto emulator
   [error] An error occurred while emulating/deploying the android project. 
...
```

I have an android virtual device!?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're just missing the correct path to ADB.  I'd recommend modifying your `$PATH` [environment variable](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm) so that it looks in the Android SDK directory and seeing if it works.